# Vectorizing a if check in a function

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function in Python which contains a `if` check

```
def test(x, a, b):
   if(x>10):
      y = a*x+b
   else:
      y = 0
   return y
```

The issue is that I have to pass `x` as a vector and get vectorized `y` output. I get the following error with mixed `x` values:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Post the numpy code that's getting the error.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the edit, at first glance, it wasn't clear this was doable in "vanilla" Python.

Comment: @Barmar: Julien's solution worked.

Comment: The key is that `x>10` is numpy boolean array.  It cannot be used in an `if` context because it has many values.  You have to explore other ways of using such an array, such as boolean indexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `np.where`:

```
def test(x, a, b):
    return np.where(x>10, a*x+b, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you just want to zero out anywhere it's false, we can simply multiply, since multiplication by `False` zeroes the values

```
def test(x, a, b):
    return (x > 10) * (a * x + b)
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the above one is a MWE. In my case, I need to assign to a constant but not zero.